# writing a R hashtable in to a CSV file?

Tags: r, csv, save, dataframe, hashtable

what i am trying to implement is to write an R hashtable to a csv file excel ( column like formatted file- keys in first column and values in the second).  please consider this example. (the hash table is created by hash package)

```
<hash> containing 5 key-value pair(s).
  1 : 4
  2 : NULL
  3 : NULL
  4 : 3 1
  5 : 1 4
```

when I simply use this

```
write.csv(hash, file = "hash.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

it gives me this error

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("hash", package = "hash")" to a data.frame
```

so i try to create a dataframe from each key and values and then bind them:

```
a<-as.data.frame(keys(hash))
b<-as.data.frame(values(hash))
Error in data.frame(`1` = "4", `2` = NULL, `3` = NULL, `4` = c("3", "1" : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0, 2
```

then to create a list and a vector :

```
a<-keys(hash)
b<-values(hash)
d<-cbind(a,b)
f<-as.data.frame(d)
  a    b
1 1    4
2 2 NULL
3 3 NULL
4 4 3, 1
5 5 1, 4
```

but then when I try to write it:

```
write.csv(f, file = "hash.csv",row.names=FALSE)
Error in .External2(C_writetable, x, file, nrow(x), p, rnames, sep, eol,  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
```

so is there any other way to do that or any way to fix this error ?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Why use a csv file? A better way to store arbitrary R objects is to use `save`.

Comment: What should be the content of the file? In particular, how do you want to treat `NULL` values?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, I rather want them to be saved in column like format

Comment: @Roland,I want them to be exactly in this format and , I want `NULL` values to be `NULL`

Comment: The problem that you are running into is that a hash is not an atomic class such as vectors or data tables. A hash value can be any R object what-so-ever.  In this way hashes are more like list and so there isn't the infrastructure for treating them as vectors or tables.  You solution is about what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

this somehow help me. but it is not yet the answer of my question as I was looking for a better solution.

```
a<-keys(hash)
  b<-values(hash)
  d<-cbind(a,b)
  L<-as.data.frame(d)
  L.df <- data.frame(lapply(L, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  write.csv(f.df, file ="file.CSV",row.names=FALSE)
    csv file format
    # a b
    # 1 4
    # 2 NULL
    # 3 NULL
    # 4 c("3", "1")
    # 5 c("1", "4")
```